# get Primavera p6 resource assigments from database?

Tags: database, resources, variable-assignment, primavera

Is it possible to get the calculated resource assignment values ​​directly from the oracle, sql or sqlite database of the projects?-for exampe monthly basis-

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the P6 Resource Assignment spread then no, it is not possible to retrieve the values from the database. You need to compute the spreads using the P6 API or the P6 WS. However, the spread information does get recorded in the extended/ reporting schema when the project is published, and you can get the information from the extended/ reporting schema tables.